# How can I use my local time as the only reference of `ntpd`?

Tags: ntp, ntpd

I want to let my Linux device synchronize its local time with the local time of another Linux server without any other references. **I don't care about the actual time. I want my fake time.** Therefore I don't need any other ntp servers for reference. For example I just set the local time of my Linux server `1.2.3.4` to `2033-02-23 15:23:10`. I want to let my Linux device synchronize this time. The config file `/etc/ntp.conf` on the Linux server is:

```
restrict 127.0.0.1 
restrict ::1

server 127.127.1.1
fudge  127.127.1.1 stratum 8

disable monitor
logfile /var/log/ntp/ntp.log
pidfile /var/run/ntpd.pid
driftfile /var/lib/ntp/drift
leapfile /etc/ntp.leapseconds
```

On the Linux client, I type `ntpdate 1.2.3.4`, and then it gives me error:

```
 5 Feb 08:26:39 ntpdate[31059]: no server suitable for synchronization found
```

Why is that? I have tested the `-d` parameter, i.e. `./ntpdate -d 1.2.3.4`, and it says:

```
 5 Feb 08:40:54 ntpdate[22958]: ntpdate 4.2.8p10@1.3728-o Mon Feb  5 10:02:23 UTC 2018 (1)
Looking for host 1.2.3.4 and service ntp
host found : 1.2.3.4
transmit(1.2.3.4)
receive(1.2.3.4)
transmit(1.2.3.4)
receive(1.2.3.4)
transmit(1.2.3.4)
receive(1.2.3.4)
transmit(1.2.3.4)
receive(1.2.3.4)
1.2.3.4: Server dropped: strata too high
server 1.2.3.4, port 123
stratum 16, precision -23, leap 11, trust 000
refid [1.2.3.4], delay 0.02573, dispersion 0.00000
transmitted 4, in filter 4
reference time:    00000000.00000000  Thu, Feb  7 2036 14:28:16.000
originate timestamp: de22269c.ab72b039  Mon, Feb  5 2018  8:41:00.669
transmit timestamp:  de22269c.ab0e1fba  Mon, Feb  5 2018  8:41:00.668
filter delay:  0.02579  0.02574  0.02573  0.02574 
         0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000 
filter offset: 0.001443 0.001416 0.001417 0.001418
         0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
delay 0.02573, dispersion 0.00000
offset 0.001417

 5 Feb 08:41:00 ntpdate[22958]: no server suitable for synchronization found
```

What is wrong with it? How can I solve this problem?

---

P.S. version information:

server:

```
[xxxx@xxxx:~]$ /usr/sbin/ntpd --version
ntpd 4.2.8p10@1.3728-o Mon Feb  5 10:02:23 UTC 2018 (1)
```

client:

```
[xxxx@xxxx:~]$ ./ntpdate -v
 5 Feb 08:36:40 ntpdate[15840]: ntpdate 4.2.8p10@1.3728-o Mon Feb  5 10:02:23 UTC 2018 (1)
 5 Feb 08:36:40 ntpdate[15840]: no servers can be used, exiting
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't use the `iburst` option on the `server` configuration line, it typically takes a few minutes after start-up for ntpd to sync with a reference clock. This is true with local clock driver too, as it is not treated as "special": it gets all the same checks as any other time source before its information is applied to ntpd's internal model of time.

If ntpd receives NTP requests before it has achieved initial synchronization, it will answer with stratum 16 and leap indicator set to 11 (= error) - and that is exactly what you are seeing.

Comment: Do you mean I need to use `server 127.127.1.1 iburst` ?

Comment: Either that, or wait a few minutes after starting ntpd before testing it. You can also run `ntpq -np` and verify that there is an asterisk in the very first column of the listing: if that asterisk isn't there, `ntpd` thinks it's out of sync and won't serve out any time information.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue.
Basically adding the iburst and prefer options made it instantly be synched and `ntpq -np` instantly showed an asterisk for the local server. Basically use

```
server 127.127.1.1 iburst prefer
fudge  127.127.1.1 stratum 8
```